# Concatenating an array to another optional values array with the “+=” operator

Tags: arrays, swift, optional-values

I have an array of object :

```
var fooArray = [Foo]()
```

If I want to append another array with Foo object i can use the `+=` :

```
fooArray += anotherFooArray
```

This one works.

But if i'm making the Foo objects in the array optional :

```
var fooArray = [Foo?]()
```

Doing the concatenation raise an error :

```
[Foo?]() is not identical to 'CGFloat'
```

I definitely don't understand what's the problem and what CGFloat type has to do with this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Foo` and `Foo?` are 2 different types (an optional is actually an instance of the `Optional<T>` enum).

In order to append into an array, the elements must be of the same type - `Foo` and `Optional<Foo>` aren't.

You can fix the problem by simply casting the array to append to an array of optional `Foo`s:

```
fooArray += anotherFooArray as [Foo?]
```

As for the misleading error message, I think that it's trying to apply an overload of the `+=` operator taking a CGFloat as one of the arguments, because it can't match the provided parameters with the overload defined for the array type.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a couple of things wrong. An array in Swift is declared like this:

```
var array = []
```

Also if you want to make your objects in the array optional, the objects that you are passing should be optional as well:

```
class Goal {}

var goal1: Goal?
var goal2: Goal?
var goal3: Goal?
var goal4: Goal?

goal2 = Goal() // Initialized
goal4 = Goal() // Initialized

var array = [goal1?, goal2?, goal3?]
```

adding new object to the array is done by appending it:

```
array.append(goal4?)
```

This example array has [nil, Goal, nil, Goal] as goal 2 and 4 are initialised and the rest are nil. If you want to add an object to the array only if it exists use binding:

```
let goal1 = goal1 {
    array.append(goal1)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: There's nothing wrong in my array declaration and you're example is kind of awful and don't answer my question. You should read Antonio's answer and some swift documentations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the array that only contains values and not `nil` s you can use `reduce` function to create new array.

```
let total: [Foo] = reduce(fooArray, otherArray) { acc, foo in
  if let foo = foo {
    return acc + [foo]
  } else {
    return acc
  }
}
```

Type of the `fooArray` is `[Foo?]` and type of `otherArray` is `[Foo]`